My kitten is 6 months old male about 2kgs yesterday he had blood in his stool
The vet has asked to either change the diet or give him homemade food. Taking is his age and weight in consideration I'm thinking to make a diet comprising of boiled chicken and rice or sweet potatos. But I don't really know how much chicken and rice to take and how much to serve him per meal

Your vet can point you to recipes for homemade cat food suitable for kittens. I would trust them rather than a website, including this one.
